# How to detect if complete substring exists in a NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I was wondering how I could check whether a complete word substring exists inside a string. As a concrete example, I would like to be able to replace the word `minute` with `foo`, and the word `minutes` with `bar`.

Currently, I am using to check whether a substring exists using:

```
if ([text rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound){
    NSLog(@"Word is found");
}
```

However, the issue I have is that since the substring `minute` is always first detected, then `minutes`, I will always get the replacement `foo`, but never `bar`. How would I be able to detect whether the entire substrings exists in a string?

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to start with the longest string. When the substrings are in an array, you could tort it first.

Comment: You could first attempt to replace `minutes`, and then attempt `minute`. This way you'd never end with `foos` in any string.

Comment: Or use regular expressions to specify that these need to be whole words.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Julian - how would I be able to start with the longest string first? I assume there would be another method similar to `rangeOfString` that I could use?

Comment: It seems regex is a good way - would you be able to supply an example as an answer for how I'd go about doing "minute" vs "minutes"? Thanks

Comment: @daspianist is right, regex would be the best. If you want to start with the longest first, put all strings you want to lookup into an array and sort it be it's containing strings lengths

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
NSString *original = @"Here is a string in a minute with loads of minutes.";

NSString *replaceMinutes = [original stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"minutes" withString:@"bar"];

NSString *replaceMinute = [replaceMinutes stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"minute" withString:@"foo"];

NSLog(replaceMinute);
```

Comment: This would make `minutes` become `foos` instead of `bar`

Answer (score 1):

You can always break up your string in an array and rebuild it to another string.

```
NSArray* stringWords = [NSString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]
```

Then you can iterate through each word and if `rangeOfString` returns found you replace it in the new string with whatever string you are replacing it with. This way it doesnt matter if its minute, minutes minutesss minutelkashdflkahsf, whatever.

Comment: Good suggestion - will give this a try and report back results.